# AWS API Gateway - Lambda Proxy (Integration Request) - Internal Server Error

Tags: aws-lambda, api-gateway

Have a simple Lambda POST integration with DynamoDB. Inserts one record into Dynamo upon execution. Works well when testing in **AWS Lambda**.

Response output is:

```
{
  "isBase64Encoded": false,
  "statusCode": 204,
  "headers": {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
    "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials": true
  },
  "body": "{}"
}
```

This response is programmatically defined as part of the Lambda response handling in accordance with [the spec](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/set-up-lambda-proxy-integrations.html#api-gateway-simple-proxy-for-lambda-output-format) (afaict).

However, when run via a test in **API Gateway**, I receive a `502` Internal server error. Am using Lambda-Proxy integration as below:

[image: API Gateway Lamba Proxy Integration]

Cloudwatch logs indicate:

```
{ ValidationException: Supplied AttributeValue is empty, must contain exactly one of the supported datatypes
at Request.extractError
```

with a limited use stacktrace (webpack has hashed the code pretty well). The above error would suggest DynamoDB is not receiving the payload correctly, or in a format it wants that honours required attributes. However, I have taken the same JSON used for the (successful) tests (tweaking the IDs to be unique between runs) from lambda, and believe my request header (Content-Type: application/json) is sensible.

Any thoughts / help on narrowing down the issue? I can post more info as requested if it helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, solved this by logging all output (and inspecting in CloudWatch), in particular the `event` object. When running in a **Lambda Test** mode, the ID and other POST attributes were passed in the root of the event object. However, when using **lambda-proxy** mode, the integration remaps the event object hierarchy, and POST attributes are JSON stringified into the `body` attribute.

Just a quirk that makes sense once you understand what it's doing. That said, it's odd that the same payload fails when testing Lambda & API Gateway in turn.